# Making Flutter Camera Fullscreen on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, camera

on an android device I am able to use this code:

```
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var scale = size.aspectRatio *
        Get.find<cameraservice>().camcontroller!.value.aspectRatio;
    if (scale < 1) {
      scale = 1 / scale;
    }
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: scale,
      child: Center(
        child: CameraPreview(Get.find<cameraservice>().camcontroller!),
      ),
    );
```

however, using the same code running on an IOS device, I see a white border on the sides.

any help would be appreciated.

using camera
camera 0.9.4+12 package.

Comment: you can use camera in scaffold's body

Answer (score 0):

Inside your **Scaffold**, you can do the following (and given that **controller** is your Camera controller instance (your ***Get.find().camcontroller!***):

```
Scaffold(
  body: Transform.scale(
    scale: controller!.value.aspectRatio / MediaQuery.of(context).size.aspectRatio,
    child: Center(
       child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: controller!.value.aspectRatio,
          child: CameraPreview(controller!)
       )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: it just stretched it out. so this didn't work

Comment: Interesting, I'm building a RTMP streaming app using the camera in full screen and that works like a charm - exactly like that.